# Visual Studio Debugger failing to connect to remote Apache Cordova app in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, remote-debugging, visual-studio-cordova

I have been trying to debug an Apache Cordova app with Visual Studio 2015 RC in a Windows 8.1 Virtual Machine. The app is running in an iOS simulator in a MAC OS host using vs-mda-remote (I've tried with different iPhone versions), but the debug always times out. There doesn't seem to be a proper error, only the following:

> Starting launch process C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\emulator.js" --platform ios  --action launch --path
>
> "C:\XXXXX\bld\ios\Debug\buildInfo.json" --serverUrl iMac-User.local:3000 --language pt-PT --cliVersion 5.1.1 --deployTarget "iPhone 5"
>
> Timed out connecting debugger to remote Apache Cordova app. See Output window for JavaScript console output.
>
> ------ Cordova Tools 5.1.1 already installed.
>
> emulated - Successfully sent to ios Simulator
>
> Emulating app at /Users/user/remote-builds/builds/5689/cordovaApp for target iPhone 5
>
> Asking to debug in remote iOS device for buildNumber 5689 in server iMac-User.local:3000...
>
> Fail to debug remote iOS in order to compile C:\XXXXX\bld\ios\Debug\buildInfo.json to http://iMac-User.local:3000 :
> iPhone 5

I have already tried to clean cordova's cache, using vs-mda-remote --secure false and some other suggestions I found online. However, nothing seems to work. It's not the project itself, as a friend of mine is able to debug it. The configuration from his computer seem to be the same as mine.

Any ideas on what might be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try launching the Simulator on you MAC side, before you try to attach  and see if that resolves the "timing" issue?

Comment: I tried launching the simulator on MAC side first, but the problem remains. I always would run several times after the simulator was opened, as my friend is also unable to connect the debug in the first time it runs, it only works for him in the second time and forward.

Comment: I think the problem is in the MAC side, as I was able to connect the VS debug when I was pointing to my friend's machine. However, even after remaking the steps to install everything a new:
> sudo npm install –g npm
> sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote
> sudo npm install –g ios-sim@3.1.1
and generating new certificates, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, there must have been something wrong with the installation of Homebrew. So I reinstalled it, and forced install ios-webkit-debug-proxy. This solved my problem and I am now able to debug the app.